# Compare two remote files from windows

Tags: windows, compare, remote-access, winmerge

I have two environment as `preprod.xxx.com` and `test.xxx.com`. After I tested everything on test environment, I merge the codes to pre-prod via TFS. After I solve conflicts and everything else I have to compare `test.xxx.com/web.js` to `preprod.xxx.com/web.js`. So I copy and paste two of them to [WinMerge](http://winmerge.org/) for compare. I am looking for when I gave two links it will compare automatically and save the session for later use.